# How to save model state in MVP and Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've implemented a basic MVP where the model has a set of messages which are displayed in a round robin fashion to the user when the screen is touched. Each message is incapsulated in `State` class and passed to the `CircularModel` implementation.

This is the Viewer code that I used to instantiate the Model and the Presenter (is it legit that they are created by the Viewer?), and also the section to restore the Model state:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ViewMVC {

    private lateinit var presenter: Presenter
    private lateinit var model : Model

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        model = if(savedInstanceState == null ) { CircularModel(LinkedList<State>(Arrays.asList(
                State("First"),
                State("Second"),
                State("Third"),
                State("Fourth"),
                State("Fifth")

        )))
        } else {
            savedInstanceState.getParcelable<Model>("model")
        }
        presenter = PresenterImpl(this, model)
    }
    // Rest of Viewer's code...
}
```

Since I want to save the state of `CirciularModel`, I made it `@Parcelize`:

```
@Parcelize
class CircularModel constructor(var states: @RawValue Deque<State>?) : Model, Parcelable {
    ...
}
```

However, in this way I have a type mismatch warning of `Model` and `Model?`. However, if I declare as `private lateinit var model : Model?` I get an error that `lateinit`can't be used with nullable types.

How can I solve this? Am I doing something wrong in the pattern implementation?

Comment: Your question is more about kotlin syntax than design patterns of any kind. That you are using a particular viewing pattern is just an example of your problem. It also has nothing to really do with Android (this problem would be identical on CLI)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `lateinit` with `Variable?`. you can read documentation from [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html)

You can create `private model:Model? = null`, so model can be null.